# Is there A way to use JavaScript to add help bubbles

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a Way with Javascript to add Help bubbles over an input Box?

For example when you you hover over an input for Name: ***_*____** it would say like First Name????

Thanks

An example is this https://edit.europe.yahoo.com/registration?.intl=uk

When you go over the name field it says First name in a bubble

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean the [title attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.4.3)?

```
<input type="text" title="First Name" />
```

Comment: Javascript dynamically generated help message

Answer (score 0):

As said in another answer you can add a title attribute to a html tag to have a tool tip display.

Or if you are after the behaviour where information is displayed somewhere on the page telling you about the text box you have selected you can; dynamically add to a div using document.createElement() and appendChild() when you [hover over the element](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseover.asp) and removing it with removeChild() upon moving your mouse away or change the [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.innerHTML) of the html tag on those two events.

**Edit:**
Unfortunately because I am a 'new' user I can't include all the hyperlinks to each part of the mozilla developer site, but simply search for those functions there for more explnation.